# Prevent specific code from being executed when imported

Tags: import, vbscript, include

I'm working on a multi-file VBScript project. Some serve as libraries (they contain `Sub`s and `Function`s only) while some others serve as program entries.

I'm using this function to import functionality from other files

```
Dim Fso
Set Fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Sub Import(ByVal FileName)
  Dim File
  Set File = Fso.OpenTextFile(FileName, 1) ' ForReading
  ExecuteGlobal File.ReadAll()
  File.Close
End Sub
```

However, sometimes I want a file to be able to run on its own while being able to be imported, and I want it to behave differently between the two cases. I think there's something equivalent to Python:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Code when run directly
```

Is there a way to do this in VBScript? Or do I have to implement a filter that removes all unwanted code manually when importing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [WScript.Script[Full]Name](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2006/08/11/how-can-i-determine-the-name-of-a-script-while-that-script-is-running/) to check whether a module is included or executed standalone.

Comment: Brilliant answer!